# Prove the inequality $1+2+3+\cdots+n\le n^2$ using induction.

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I know how to solve equalities with induction, but this was my first induction. I just wanted to know if this is correct, and if not, where did I go wrong? 
Thanks :)
[image]

Comment: You have assumed what is was that you were required to prove $\ddot\frown$

Comment: All the tutorial videos I have watched have you assume this. Now that I look at it, it doesn't make sense to do that. Is there an alternative way of doing it?

Comment: Start with maybe the LHS of the inequality you want to prove and work your way towards showing it is at most the RHS

Comment: There are ways of presenting it the way you have but it doesn't read nicely. And involves a whole bunch of "if and only ifs"

Comment: "Since this statement is true the implication itself is true" Bulls###. elephants dance the fandango to fleas playing violins => violins are musical instruments.  Since violins being musical instruments are true, the statement must be true.

Comment: You're not wrong ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An argument "$X$ is true because $X$ implies a true statement" is [fallacious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent) even though sometimes these arguments map to a sound argument if you run them backwards.

Here is one correct approach: First we have  $$1 + 2+\ldots+k+(k+1) \le k^2+(k+1)$$ since by the induction hypothesis, $1+2+\ldots +k \le k^2.$ Then we can complete the square to write  $$k^2+k+1 =
 (k+1)^2-k.$$ Plugging that into the RHS, we have $$1 + 2+\ldots+k+(k+1) \le (k+1)^2-k.$$ Finally since $k> 0$ we have $$ (k+1)^2-k < (k+1)^2$$ so we can conclude$$1 + 2+\ldots+k+(k+1)  < (k+1)^2.$$

Comment: ah, that's what I had done initially. I guess I will be using that now. Thanks!

Comment: @CraigD That's not at all what you did in your problem statement. (Unless by initially, you meant before you posted this.)

Comment: That is indeed what I meant :)

Comment: I still don't completely understand your solution. Can I edit mine and repost it so you can direct me?

Comment: How did you get from the top to the bottom? https://gyazo.com/065f037d09fe867934a1ae714d278011

Comment: nvm i didnt get it

Comment: $(k+1)^2-k = (k^2+2k+1-k) = k^2+k+1.$

Comment: https://gyazo.com/e280be9ae482eb612af5ef4b788110f0 This is the closest I could get

Comment: @CraigD $k^2 +k +1 < k^2 + 2k +1 = (k+1)^2$

Comment: @CraigD You don't seem to be following the argument. I wrote it out in more detail.

Comment: Ohh. Okay, thanks so much. I get it now. Thanks for your time man

Answer (score 1):

Don't go from what you want to prove back.  Go from what you know forward.

$1+2+....... + k \le k^2$

$(1+2+....... + k) + k+1 \le (k^2) + k +1 < k^2 + 2k + 1 = (k+1)^2$.

That's it.  *one* line.